# JavaScript: Change text color with a button, each time the button is clicked a different style should show up. Not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm fairly new to JavaScript. I just made this simple script:

[HTML code]

```
<html>
<body>

<script src="externalscript.js"></script>

<p id="text">This text will change style</p><br>
<button type="button" onclick="changeStyle()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

[JS code]

```
function changeStyle() {

status = 1;
x = document.GetElementById("text");

if(status==1) {
    x.style.color = 'blue';
    status = 2;
}

if(status==2) {
    x.style.color = 'red';
    status = 3;
}

if(status==3) {
    x.style.color = 'yellow';
    status = 1;
}

}
```

I want it to change the text to a different style each time the button is clicked. However, this is not working. Could anyone explain a way to do this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is

```
getElementById("text")
```

not

```
GetElementById("text");
```

Also if i get what are you trying to achieve you should put `status = 1;` outside the function. Declare it as a global variable so that you cab change it inside each if.

Also you have to use `else_if` instead of `if`

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jeGCz)

Comment: Glad to help. You didnt declare what are you trying to achieve so i made i quess. I will edited now that i know

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
status = 1;
function changeStyle() {
//Note the lowercase first letter.
x = document.getElementById("text");

if(status==1) {
    x.style.background-color = 'blue';
    status = 2;
}
else if(status==2) {
    x.style.background-color = 'red';
    status = 3;
}
else if(status==3) {
    x.style.background-color = 'yellow';
    status = 1;
}

}
```

You need to use 'else if' because otherwise the browser, after changing the color, immediately moves unto the next if block, and thinks "well that's true now", and then runs that code, all the way to the end of your current code. Using 'else if' tell the browser to ignore the other 'if blocks' once the first one is evaluated.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define variable `status=1` outside the function,otherwise each time when button clicking it will set to 1.Also need to change `GetElementById("text");` to`getElementById("text");`

```
status = 1;
function changeStyle() {    

x = document.getElementById("text");

if(status==1) {
    x.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    status = 2;
}
else if(status==2) {
    x.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    status = 3;
}
else if(status==3) {
    x.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    status = 1;
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>
         login page
      </title>
      <style>
         #body{
         line-height: 35px;
         }
         span {
         color: black;
         font-family: monospace;
         }
         button {
         margin-right: 10px;
         font-family: monospace;
         }
         .green {
         background-color: green;
         }
         .blue {
         background-color: blue;
         }
         .red {
         background-color: red;
         }
         .gray {
         background-color: gray;
         }
         .black {
         background-color: black;
         color: white;
         }
         #text {
         font-size: 20px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="body">
         <div>
            <span>Select the color for text</span><br>
            <button onclick="green()" class="green">Green</buttton>
            <button onclick="blue()" class="blue">Blue</buttton>
            <button onclick="red()" class="red">Red</buttton>
            <button onclick="gray()" class="gray">Gray</buttton>
            <button onclick="black()" class="black">Black</buttton>
         </div>
         <br>
         <div>
            <span>Select the color for background</span><br>
            <button onclick="document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';" 

          class="green">Green</buttton>
                <button onclick="document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';" 
          class="blue">Blue</buttton>
                <button onclick="document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';" 
          class="red">Red</buttton>
                <button onclick="document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'gray';" 
          class="gray">Gray</buttton>
                <button onclick="document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';" ` 
         class="black">Black</buttton>`
         </div>
         <div>
            <span id="text">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing 
            elit. Incidunt ea non accusamus at iure illo quasi deserunt commodi 
             magnam, quo optio illum nobis voluptas saepe, dolorem recusandae fuga 
           modi ut.</span>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script>
         //change the text color
         function green() {
             document.getElementById("text").style = "color:green";
         }
         function blue() {
             document.getElementById("text").style = "color:blue";
         }
         function red() {
             document.getElementById("text").style = "color:red";
         }
         function gray() {
             document.getElementById("text").style = "color:gray";
         }
         function black() {
             document.getElementById("text").style = "color:black";
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code, e.g. how it solves the problem